# Remove all items except specific from array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Trying to remove all items from the array inside object but getting this error **Cannot delete property '0' of [object Array]**

object array:

```
       let tempBrand = [
          {
         name: "Toshiba",
         models:["Toshiba Excite Pro","Toshiba Regza AT300","Toshiba Regza AT1S0","Toshiba Folio 
         100","Toshiba G500","Toshiba AT720"]
         }
        ]

       let tagsData= ["Toshiba Regza AT300","Toshiba Regza AT1S0"]
```

this is what I'm trying to do.

```
       for (let i = 0; i < tempBrand.length; i++){
            tempBrand[i].models.length = 0;
            for (let j = 0; j < tempBrand[i].models.length; j++){
                if (tempBrand[i].models[j] !== tagsData[i]) {
                    delete tempBrand[i].models[j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use `filter()` method to filter out the item you need. If you want to mutate the original array, find the index of the item you want to remove and then use `splice()` method.

Comment: `tempBrand` is an object so you cannot do `for (let i = 0; i < tempBrand.length; i++){
` on it.

Comment: how can i filter item and save it into same array inside object? any help would be appreciated

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli sorry typo i corrected it. its an array not an object.

Comment: @SyedDanishAliJr. now it is just an invalid array. Please post actual data and code

Comment: anyway what you want (*for filtering out models not in `tagsData`*) is `tempBrand[i].models = tempBrand[i].models.filter( model => tagsData.includes(model))`. And do not set the `length` of an array to 0 because that empties the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve but here is my implementation about what I understood from your problem.
As you have updated the question here is the updated answer.
If you want to persist with the iterative approach you can use that or else as mentioned in the comments you can use es6 methods for functional style of coding.

```
let tempBrand = [
         {
         name: "Toshiba",
         models:["Toshiba Excite Pro","Toshiba Regza AT300","Toshiba Regza AT1S0","Toshiba Folio 100","Toshiba G500","Toshiba AT720"]
        }
        ]

       let tagsData= ["Toshiba Regza AT300","Toshiba Regza AT1S0"];
 
 for (let i=0 ; i<tempBrand.length;i++)
for(let j=0 ; j<tempBrand[i].models.length;j++){
    if(tagsData.includes(tempBrand[i].models[j]))
    {
      console.log({item : tempBrand[i].models[j]});
      tempBrand[i].models.splice(j, 1); 
     }   
}
console.log({tempBrand})
```

Comment: Do not remove items from an array while you are iterating it increasingly.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli thank you for suggestion. I just used the example he shared above so that he can understand better, if he is not use to of es6.  :)